# C++ Directx 3D: Drawing rectangles with alternate colours

Tags: c++, directx-9

I am new to DirectX (3D) and working on a requirement to draw continuous rectangle on top of the screen in Borland C++. I am able to draw rectangle by following tutorial http://www.directxtutorial.com/Lesson.aspx?lessonid=9-4-1.

But my problem is:
1. I will be continuously drawing rectangle from Right to Left of the screen.
2. Now, while drawing this rectangle, every 30-seconds it should alter colours. First 30-seconds, say blue and next 30-seconds green. After 30-seconds again blue and after 30 again green. Like this colours should be alternate.

I am able to draw rectangle and every 30-seconds it is changing colours. First it will draw blue for some pixels and after 30-seconds it will draw green. But when it is changing colour to green, it is changing blue portion as well. (This function is called by a timer function for every 50ms and I am re-drawing complete screen).

Can anybody suggest any alternatives to the above approach or any thought on this approach to draw alternate rectangles/ colours on rectangles?

```
struct CUSTOMVERTEX {
        FLOAT x, y, z, rhw; // from the D3DFVF_XYZRHW flag
        DWORD color; // from the D3DFVF_DIFFUSE flag
    };

CUSTOMVERTEX OurVertices[4];

if (!d3ddev)
        return;

    float xscale = texWidth / 1024.0;
    if (xscale < 1.0)
        xscale = 1.0;

    VOID* pVoid; // the void* we were talking about

    mark->Lock(0, 0, (void**) & pVoid,  0);


        OurVertices[0].x = (float)x1 * xscale;
        OurVertices[0].y = 5;
        //OurVertices[0].z = 0;
        OurVertices[0].rhw = 1.0f;

        OurVertices[1].x = (float)x2 * xscale;
        OurVertices[1].y = 5;
        //OurVertices[1].z = 0;
        OurVertices[1].rhw = 1.0f;

        OurVertices[2].x = (float)x1 * xscale;
        OurVertices[2].y = 15;
        //OurVertices[2].z = 0;
        OurVertices[2].rhw = 1.0f;

        OurVertices[3].x = (float)x2 * xscale;
        OurVertices[3].y = 15;
        //OurVertices[3].z = 0;
        OurVertices[3].rhw = 1.0f;

        if (!drawMMarker)
        {
            OurVertices[0].color = D3DCOLOR_XRGB(64, 64, 64);
            OurVertices[1].color = D3DCOLOR_XRGB(64, 64, 64);
            OurVertices[2].color = D3DCOLOR_XRGB(64, 64, 64);
            OurVertices[3].color = D3DCOLOR_XRGB(64, 64, 64);

        }
        else
        {
            OurVertices[0].color = D3DCOLOR_XRGB(128, 128, 128);
            OurVertices[1].color = D3DCOLOR_XRGB(128, 128, 128);
            OurVertices[2].color = D3DCOLOR_XRGB(128, 128, 128);
            OurVertices[3].color = D3DCOLOR_XRGB(128, 128, 128);
            drawMMarker = false;
        }
        memcpy(pVoid, OurVertices, sizeof(OurVertices));

        // copy vertices to the vertex buffer
        mark->Unlock(); // unlock v_buffer

        d3ddev->SetFVF(CUSTOMFVF);
        d3ddev->SetStreamSource(0, mark, 0, sizeof(CUSTOMVERTEX));
        d3ddev->DrawPrimitive(D3DPT_TRIANGLESTRIP, 0, 2);
```

The above routine will be called from a timer.

Comment: Can you show the code you have so far?

Comment: Posting code as another question as comment space is not sufficient